# Simulate android shake

Tags: android, cordova, hockeyapp, testfairy

Is there an API method that can be used to simulate shaking an Android device?  My reason for wanting to do this -

I had been experimenting with using [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net) to provide an in-app feedback facility for my beta testers.  Whilst it works I find that in my hybrid Cordova app it displays an ugly feedback screen which

1. stays put till I hit the Back button
2. at which point it restarts the app - I suspect because it uses the WebView to display the feedback screen so in effect the app's own screen has to reload later

TestFairy provide a much sleeker UX when offering feedback and their "shake for feedback" concept is very nice.  However, it may not be apparent to all my beta testers so I would like to provide a button which I can then use to simulate the shake gesture from the custom Cordova plugin that I am also writing for the app.